# Dynamically add content to a scrollable div

Tags: jquery

I am having a scrollable div and I wish to append content to the div on the scroll event of the div.
So whenever the scroll event gets fired , content gets appended to the div but they are not getting displayed in the scrolling area.

So please help me  in displaying the newly added content in the scrolling area

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
$("#scrollDiv").bind("scroll", function(){
    $(this).append("HTML HERE");
});
```

Comment: correct you are. He can also use `.html()` if he needs to append only the content rather elements.

Comment: If you are using the `.html()` function all the content will be replaced, with `.append()` you can add html. Which is the goal of the question starter.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to append content that is visible or not visible on scroll?
A good place to start is the [scroll](http://api.jquery.com/scroll) event

Answer (score 0):

Here's the event for scrolling: http://api.jquery.com/scroll/

Using the handler, you can use html() to insert content in your div by for example referring to the ID or class.

Although, I am not sure what you are trying to achieve by doing this.